# css bootstrap alignment issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having troubles aligning things in a table row. I have an hyperlink and an inline-form made up of one textbox and one button. 
The problem is that the button goes to the next line instead of being aligned with the textbox. The problem occurs in Chrome, but it works fine in IE10

I use twitter bootstrap for css. This jsfiddle illustrates the problem : http://jsfiddle.net/Tq9Qm/

Can you help me ?

the code of jsfiddle:

```
<table class="view-header">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td> <span>Edition du mandat  </span>

        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="pull-right"> <a style="float: left;">
                   <span class="pointer">more options</span>

                </a>

                <form class="form-inline" placeholder="N° de contrat, nom/numéro de client">
                    <input class="input-xxlarge ng-dirty" type="text" placeholder="N° de contrat, nom/numéro de client" ng-model="model" />
                    <button disabled="disabled" class="btn btn-info" type="submit" ng-click="searchMethod()" ng-disabled=" ! canSearch()"><i class="icon-search"></i>&nbsp;Rechercher</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <div class="pull-right">
                <!-- uiIf: filterVisible -->
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try** `pull-left` in your form

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohit_azad/Tq9Qm/1/)**

Comment: nice one, it was easy as that. Thank you ! (I'll mark this as answer in 10 minutes, SO does not allow me now).

Answer (score 2):

Use `pull-left` it's attribute for twitter boot-strap

#### FiddleDemo

[Nav Documentation](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#navs)

Answer (score 0):

try the `pull-left` attribute

it will helps you